Google Ads- googleadservices.com returns 400
I'm facing an issue with Google Ads event tracking. All requests to googleadservices.com (for every event) are returning a 400 Bad Request status.
However, I've noticed that if I change the URL parameter to something other than my domain, the request responds with a 200 status, which seems correct.
Google support mentioned that the error might be due to a "blocked_by_orb" issue, but I can't see anything on my end that would be causing this. I've already tried the following:
Disabled all firewalls
Checked robots.txt for any blocking rules
Unfortunately, none of this has resolved the problem. Has anyone encountered something similar or have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot further?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Hi, have you found out the answer? We also started to have this problem around 1 month ago, I checked multiple options, but no luck so far
